# C#: Какими средствами можно реализовать получение почты на C#?

Tags: c#, imap, pop3

Доброго времени суток!
Возникла необходимость парсить почту на Gmail`е. Подскажите пожалуйста средства для подобной реализации.

Заранее с благодарностью!

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы кто то писал за вас код или у вас уже есть код, который не работает?

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопросы о поиске программ/библиотек [не стоит задавать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ на англоязычном форуме. Рекомендуют OpenPOP.NET.
Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Судя по всему (и названию в первую очередь) библиотека поддерживает только протокол POP, как-то, прямо скажем, не богато. Пользуйтесь [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit), проверено годами.

Comment: Благодарю за совет!